# Update a complex object without changing its order and recreate

Tags: java, java-8

I have a complex object with a lot of nested data.

This is an example. It can come in different variations and nesting.

```
{
    "name": "name",
    "age": 12,
    "height": 1.50
    "body": {
        "detail1": "detail1",
        "detail2": "detail2"
        "detail3": "detail3"
        "detail4": ["detail4", ""]
    },
    "arr": [1, 2, 3],
    "arr2": ["", "", ""],
    "bod2": {
        "child": {
            "name": "a",
            "name2": "b"
        }
    }
}
```

I wish to traverse this entire object, and every time a value is a `String`, I want to append another String to it, example `" Hello"`.

Resulting in:

```
{
    "name": "name Hello",
    "age": 12,
    "height": 1.50
    "body": {
        "detail1": "detail1 Hello",
        "detail2": "detail2 Hello"
        "detail3": "detail3 Hello"
        "detail4": ["detail4 Hello", "Hello"]
    },
    "arr": [1, 2, 3],
    "arr2": [" Hello", " Hello", " Hello"],
    "bod2": {
        "child": {
            "name": "a Hello",
            "name2": "b Hello"
        }
    }
}
```

Once I have gone through the entire object, return the updated object where all string values are now appended with "world".

I want to preferably do this without having to create an object.

But more importantly, I don't want to change the order.

Such as in above, the key name is first, followed by age, height body and so on. I want to maintain this order, same for the nesting data.

I came up with the following but this doesnt maintain the order and I am also recreating objects.

Is there a way I could interate through the whole object, every parts of it and update all the String for the object?

```
public static Object updateStrings(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof String) {
        return ((String) obj) + "hello";
    } else if (obj instanceof Object[]) {
        Object[] arr = (Object[]) obj;
        Object[] updatedArr = new Object[arr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            updatedArr[i] = updateStrings(arr[i]);
        }
        return updatedArr;
    } else if (obj instanceof Map) {
        Map<Object, Object> map = (Map<Object, Object>) obj;
        Map<Object, Object> updatedMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            updatedMap.put(entry.getKey(), updateStrings(entry.getValue()));
        }
        return updatedMap;
    } else {
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: "*But more importantly, I don't want to change the order.*" - Where is this constrain coming from? According to [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159), "*An object is an **unordered** collection of zero or more name/value pairs, where a name is a string and a value is a string, number, boolean, null, object, or array. ...*"

Comment: @Turing85 Maybe wrong choice of words. The object being passed in is a custom class. This is then returned as a response in a rest service. I just don't want to mess up that order in the response. More for visual purposes during dev.

Comment: Why don't you show the actual object populated with data instead of what amounts to so many lines of text?  Showing the class, actually populated with data would help others benefit from this question.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a JSON object?

Comment: @Turing85 well, it’s JSON, so the same document [avoids calling order retaining parser wrong](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#:~:text=JSON%20parsing%20libraries,by%20these%20differences.): “*JSON parsing libraries have been observed to differ as to whether or not they make the ordering of object members visible to calling software.  Implementations whose behavior does not depend on member ordering will be interoperable in the sense that they will not be affected by these differences.*”

Answer (score 0):

Below method should do what you want if you are willing to use jackson library which is commonly used:

```
public static Object updateStringsInObjWithText (String jsonStr, String suffix) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, Object> constructedObj = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, Map.class);
        JsonNode tree = mapper.valueToTree(constructedObj);

        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> fields = tree.fields();
        while (fields.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> field = fields.next();
            String fieldKey = field.getKey();
            JsonNode fieldValue = field.getValue();
            if (fieldValue.isValueNode() && fieldValue instanceof TextNode) {
                constructedObj.put(fieldKey, fieldValue.textValue() + suffix);
            } else if (!fieldValue.isValueNode() && fieldValue instanceof ArrayNode) {
                int size = fieldValue.size();
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    JsonNode subNode = fieldValue.get(i);
                    if (subNode instanceof TextNode) {
                        ((ArrayNode) fieldValue).set(i, mapper.createArrayNode().add(subNode.textValue() + suffix).get(0));
                    }
                }
                constructedObj.put(fieldKey, fieldValue);
            } else if (!fieldValue.isValueNode()) {
                Object tempObj = updateStringsInObjWithText(mapper.writeValueAsString(fieldValue), suffix);
                constructedObj.put(fieldKey, tempObj);
            } else {
            }
        }
        return constructedObj;
    }
```

Here is how you use it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String json = "{\n" +
                "    \"name\": \"name\",\n" +
                "    \"age\": 12,\n" +
                "    \"height\": 1.50,\n" +
                "    \"body\": {\n" +
                "        \"detail1\": \"detail1\",\n" +
                "        \"detail2\": \"detail2\",\n" +
                "        \"detail3\": \"detail3\",\n" +
                "        \"detail4\": [\"detail4\", \"\"]\n" +
                "    },\n" +
                "    \"arr\": [1, 2, 3],\n" +
                "    \"arr2\": [\"\", \"\", \"\"],\n" +
                "    \"bod2\": {\n" +
                "        \"child\": {\n" +
                "            \"name\": \"a\",\n" +
                "            \"name2\": \"b\"\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "}";

        Object obj = updateStringsInObjWithText(json, " hello");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(obj));

    }
```

And the response you get should be:

```
{
  "name" : "name hello",
  "age" : 12,
  "height" : 1.5,
  "body" : {
    "detail1" : "detail1 hello",
    "detail2" : "detail2 hello",
    "detail3" : "detail3 hello",
    "detail4" : [ "detail4 hello", " hello" ]
  },
  "arr" : [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  "arr2" : [ " hello", " hello", " hello" ],
  "bod2" : {
    "child" : {
      "name" : "a hello",
      "name2" : "b hello"
    }
  }
}
```

And if you dont want to start with a JSON string and want to use an object directly, you can overload the above method as follows:

```
public static Object updateStringsInObjWithText ( Object obj, String suffix) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, Object> constructedObj = (Map<String, Object>) obj;
        JsonNode tree = mapper.valueToTree(constructedObj);

        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> fields = tree.fields();
        while (fields.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> field = fields.next();
            String fieldKey = field.getKey();
            JsonNode fieldValue = field.getValue();
            if (fieldValue.isValueNode() && fieldValue instanceof TextNode) {
                constructedObj.put(fieldKey, fieldValue.textValue() + suffix);
            } else if (!fieldValue.isValueNode() && fieldValue instanceof ArrayNode) {
                int size = fieldValue.size();
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    JsonNode subNode = fieldValue.get(i);
                    if (subNode instanceof TextNode) {
                        ((ArrayNode) fieldValue).set(i, mapper.createArrayNode().add(subNode.textValue() + suffix).get(0));
                    }
                }
                constructedObj.put(fieldKey, fieldValue);
            } else if (!fieldValue.isValueNode()) {
                Object tempObj = updateStringsInObjWithText(mapper.writeValueAsString(fieldValue), suffix);
                constructedObj.put(fieldKey, tempObj);
            } else {
            }
        }
        return constructedObj;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
public static Object updateStrings(Object obj, String suffix) {
    if (obj instanceof String) {
        return ((String) obj) + suffix;
    } else if (obj instanceof Object[]) {
        Object[] arr = (Object[]) obj;
        Object[] updatedArr = new Object[arr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            updatedArr[i] = updateStrings(arr[i], suffix);
        }
        return updatedArr;
    } else if (obj instanceof Map) {
        Map<Object, Object> map = (Map<Object, Object>) obj;
        Map<Object, Object> updatedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            updatedMap.put(entry.getKey(), updateStrings(entry.getValue(), suffix));
        }
        return updatedMap;
    } else {
        return obj;
    }
}
```

You can call this function by passing in the object and the desired suffix to append:

```
Object originalObject = // your original object
Object updatedObject = updateStrings(originalObject, " Hello");
```